# ClassCastException while fetching edge property value bewteen two vertices

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to fetch edge property value between two vertices and getting below exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   scala.runtime.Nothing$

Env: Titan InMemory

Code :

```
val age = Key[Int]("age")

 A ---("knows",age -> 10) --> B
```

Gremlin query:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "A").bothE("knows").as("x").otherV()
      .has("ID", "B").select("x").properties("age").headOption().get
```

output : **p[age->10]**

```
graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "A").bothE("knows").as("x").otherV()
          .has("ID", "B").select("x").label().head()
```

output : **knows**

```
graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "A").bothE("knows").as("x").otherV()
      .has("ID", "B").select("x").values("age").head()
```

Output:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   scala.runtime.Nothing$

Any idea when i try to fetch property value , i am getting this error

Same works with gremlin console
http://gremlinbin.com/bin/view/58044fa931772

Comment: That traversal should work. Might be an issue with the scala plugin. May want to raise this as an issue on github.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Currently i am using `com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.0.2-incubating.2` version. Do i need to move any higher version of scala

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is correct solution.
This resolved my problem.

I was inserting integer value to edge property

Before:  `mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(classOf[String]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()`

After :

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(classOf[Integer]).cardinality(Cardinality.SET).make()
```

After changing this , below error was occuring

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   scala.runtime.Nothing$

Before :

```
val age_value = graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "A").bothE("knows").as("x").otherV()
      .has("ID", "B").select("x").values("age").head()
```

After :

```
val age_value:Integer = graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "A").bothE("knows").as("x").otherV()
      .has("ID", "B").select("x").values("age").head()
```