# select multiple edge property values from list of edges and put in list[List]

Tags: scala, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I am having vertices with multiple edges having same labels. Edges having properties like **age1**,**age2** and **time** in it.

Example:

A-->B => **age1** = 10, **age2**=10 and **time** = t1

A-->B => **age1** = 20, **age2**=30 and **time** = t1

A-->B => **age1** = 30, **age2**=50 and **time** = t1

I need to form two **list[List[]]** with the above the edges with specific time

eg : **List[[10,10][20,30][30,50]]**

```
graph.traversal.V().has(ID,"A").bothE("interference").
where(_.values("time").is(P.gt("sometime"))).values("age1").as("x").values("age2").as("y").select("x","y").toList()
```

It is giving some compilation error.
Am i doing something wrong in the query

Compilation Error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter p:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.Prepend[shapeless.HNil,shapeless.::[A,shapeless.HNil]]
>         .where(_.values("time").is(P.gt(endtime))).values("age1").as("x")

Comment: What is the compilation error you are seeing? I noticed on your other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40078365/1831717) that you were getting errors with scala that didn't occur with gremlin in the groovy console...perhaps this is another incompatibility?

Comment: @stephenmallette I have added the error. It is because `where(_.values("time").is(P.gt("sometime")))` this code gives list of edges  and hence i cannot do `.values("age1").as("x")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solves this problem

Scala gremlin:

```
 graph.traversal.V().has(ID,"A").bothE("interference").
    where(_.values("time").is(P.gt("sometime"))).valueMap("age1","age2").toList()
```

Gremlin console:

```
graph.traversal().V().has('ID', 'a').bothE("interference").valueMap('age1','age2')
==>{age2=50, age1=10}
==>{age2=50, age1=30}
==>{age2=20, age1=60}
```